# Grails background process that checks time

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there a way in grails through out my application I can check for date/time for the records in list(). It compares with current date and time. Once that date is passed , the record in the lists shows Inactive label in list table.????

Comment: This needs to be outside of your application? You can create a new column in your list.gsp table and just check the date in your record and the actual date in the server.

Comment: Thanks @SérgioMichels! I will check it I can use this.

Comment: @SérgioMichels worked for me. But what if i want to insert that value into the database table as well. that internally checks with current date and date/time column.Thank you!

Comment: Instead of inserting in the database, maybe it's better to just create a [transient attribute](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html) in your domain class with a getter that return the status.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case for Quartz: http://grails.org/plugin/quartz

Quartz runs like cron jobs and runs code at specific intervals.

We have several Quartz jobs that run every few minutes to monitor a directory and process all files in the directory.

You could set up a quartz job to call a Service that does what you want.

You could also look into some of the interceptors, like onLoad, to see if you could accomplish something like this: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping